# Sublime text 3 MinGW build

Tags: io, sublimetext3, sublime-build

I've been trying to build sublime text 3 for competitive programming and am getting confused about build systems. I've tried various build systems from the net and some start the console for i/o ,some show some error and don't work. I have downloaded MinGW as C:\MinGW\bin . I require a build which inputs from a file "input.txt" and outputs to "output.txt". Here is my sample code which I'm trying to run.

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqCu0.png)

What it does is open the console and even when I enter the input (present in the image), it doesn't give output.
The build -

```
{
"cmd": ["gcc", "${file}", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe"],
"file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"selector": "source.c, source.c++",
"shell": true,

"variants":
[
    {
        "name": "Run",
        "cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/k", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}.exe"],
        "shell": true
    }
] }
```